# Can we solve this using a greedy strategy? If not how do we solve this using dynamic programming?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

Problem:

The city of Siruseri is impeccably planned. The city is divided into a rectangular array of cells with M rows and N columns. Each cell has a metro station. There is one train running left to right and back along each row, and one running top to bottom and back along each column. Each trains starts at some time T and goes back and forth along its route (a row or a column) forever.

Ordinary trains take two units of time to go from one station to the next. There are some fast trains that take only one unit of time to go from one station to the next. Finally, there are some slow trains that take three units of time to go from one station the next. You may assume that the halting time at any station is negligible.
Here is a description of a metro system with 3 rows and 4 columns:

```
S(1) F(2) O(2) F(4)
F(3) . . . .
S(2) . . . .
O(2) . . . .
```

The label at the beginning of each row/column indicates the type of train (F for fast, O for ordinary, S for slow) and its starting time. Thus, the train that travels along row 1 is a fast train and it starts at time 3. It starts at station (1,1) and moves right, visiting the stations along this row at times 3, 4, 5 and 6 respectively. It then returns back visiting the stations from right to left at times 6, 7, 8 and 9. It again moves right now visiting the stations at times 9, 10, 11 and 12, and so on. Similarly, the train along column 3 is an ordinary train starting at time 2. So, starting at the station (3,1), it visits the three stations on column 3 at times 2, 4 and 6, returns back to the top of the column visiting them at times 6,8 and 10, and so on.

Given a starting station, the starting time and a destination station, your task is to determine the earliest time at which one can reach the destination using these trains.
For example suppose we start at station (2,3) at time 8 and our aim is to reach the station (1,1). We may take the slow train of the second row at time 8 and reach (2,4) at time 11. It so happens that at time 11, the fast train on column 4 is at (2,4) travelling upwards, so we can take this fast train and reach (1,4) at time 12. Once again we are lucky and at time 12 the fast train on row 1 is at (1,4), so we can take this fast train and reach (1,1) at time 15. An alternative route would be to take the ordinary train on column 3 from (2,3) at time 8 and reach (1,3) at time 10. We then wait there till time 13 and take the fast train on row 1 going left, reaching (1,1) at time 15. You can verify that there is no way of reaching (1,1) earlier than that.

> Test Data: You may assume that M, N ≤ 50.
>   Time Limit: 3 seconds

As the size of N,M is very small we can try to solve it by recursion.

At every station, we take two trains which can take us nearer to our destination. 
E.g.: If we want to go to 1,1 from 2,3 , we take the trains which take us more near to 2,3 and get down to the nearest station to our destination, while keeping track of the time we take, if we reach the destination, we keep track of the minimum time so far, and if the time taken to reach the destination is lesser than the minimum we update it.

We can determine which station a train is at a particular time using this method:

```
/* S is the starting time of the train and N is the number of stations it
 visits, T is the time for which we want to find the station the train is at. 
T always be greater than S*/

T = T-S+1
Station(T) = T%N, if T%N = 0, then Station(T) = N;
```

Here is my question:

- How do we determine the earliest time when a particular train reaches the station we want in the direction we want?
- As my above algorithm uses greedy strategy, will it give an accurate answer? If not then how do I approach this problem?

P.S : This is not homework, it is an [online judge problem](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/METRO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe greedy solution will fail here, but it will be a bit hard to construct a counter-example.

This problem is meant to be solved using Dijkstra's algorithm. Edges are the connection between adjacent nodes and depend on the type of train and its starting time. You also **don't need** to compute the whole graph - only compute edged for the current node you are considering. I have solved numerous similar problems and this is the way you solved. Also tried to use greedy several times before I learnt it never passes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But in Dijkstra's algorithm, to find 'minimum-weight-edge' we do need to compute all the edges.

Comment: Not true. You need to find the minimum weight edge going out of the "special part" of the graph i.e. the set of nodes you have already visited. I hope I get the term right in English.

Comment: You start from the given cell and compute which is the earliest moment at which you can get to one of its adjacent nodes. You update min distance to all those nodes, choose the closest one and continue from it. Now you consider that node - a cell, together with the time you are at it. You calculate when at earliest you can get to its neighbors and update min distances again. Continue doing until you visit the target node. Only visit a node if it is closest from all possible neighbors of the visited set! I can write the whole solution but that is not the idea of these problems - try do it alone

Comment: One more thing, do we move only in the direction of our destination or everywhere?

Comment: everywhere. Because of the different weights the `bean search` will not do(the solution you propose). This would have been a greedy solution if it worked.